# re-arrange pythonpath in pydev-eclipse?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I'm using pydev in eclipse.

I was hoping that pydev would first use the python classes I develop in my source dir. but since I also install the built egg into system dir, pydev also picks up the classes from system dir.

the problem is that pydev uses system dir first in its python path. so after I installed a buggy version, and debug through pydev, and made the necessary changes in local sourcecode, it does not take effect, since the installed egg is not changed. or in the reverse case, as I was debugging, pydev takes me to the egg files, and I modify those egg files, so the real source code is not changed.

so How could I let pydev rearrange pythonpath order? (just like eclipse does for java build classpath) ?

thanks
yang

Comment: There is an interesting file in my workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.python.pydev/v1_[...]/pythonpath. Unfortunately changing and resarting eclipse didn't have the expected effect.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using setuptools, you can try running `sudo python setup.py develop` on the egg as well as adding project dependencies between the two in Eclipse